# Spark: Override library method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science

I would like to make some modifications to the scala code of `spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression` without having to rebuild the whole Spark. 
Since we can append jar files to the execution of either spark-submit, or pySpark.  Is it possible to compile a modified copy of `LogisticRegression.java` and override the default methods of Spark, or at least create new ones? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new Class extending `org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression`, and overriding the respective methods without modification of the source code should work.

```
class CustomLogisticRegression
  extends
    LogisticRegression {
  override def toString(): String = "This is overridden Logistic Regression Class"
}
```

Running Logistic Regression with the new `CustomLogisticRegression` class

```
val data = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "/opt/spark/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt"))

val customLR = new CustomLogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

val customLRModel = customLR.fit(data)

val originalLR = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

val originalLRModel = originalLR.fit(data)

// Print the intercept for logistic regression
println(s"Custom Class's Intercept: ${customLRModel.intercept}")
println(s"Original Class's Intercept: ${originalLRModel.intercept}")
println(customLR.toString())
println(originalLR.toString())
```

Output:

```
Custom Class's Intercept: 0.22456315961250317
Original Class's Intercept: 0.22456315961250317
This is overridden Logistic Regression Class
logreg_1cd811a145d7
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful!

Comment: What if `LogisticRegression` is already created, and I have to cast from `LogisticRegression` to `CustomLogisticRegression` ?